# Displaying duplicate values within a dataframe -> key error

Tags: python, pandas

I have an csv file that contains a column with multiple values (some of the values can appear several times within the sheet). The following piece of code returns an error. What is the solution ? Keep in mind that i have to display the duplicated values each times they appears.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["123", "678", "123", "454", "123"]})
df["ID"] = [f for f in df["ID"] if df["ID"].count(f) > 1]
KeyError: 'Level (output omitted)  must be same as name (None)'
```

The output should be: 123, 123, 123. (for three times)

Comment: [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html#pandas.Series.count) counts the number of non-null elements in the series, not the occurrence of a specific value `f` like you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use:

```
duplicates = df[df.duplicated()]
```

Output:

```
    ID
2  123
4  123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `duplicated` function to identify the duplicated value combined with a list comprehension to make sure you get all of the values (since duplicated only returns the duplicates and not the original :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["123", "678", "123", "454", "123"]})
duplicates = [x for x in df['ID']  if x in df[df.duplicated()].values]
```

---

```
['123', '123', '123']
```